# how to join 2 mysql queries in php as hetml return value

Tags: php, html, mysql, join

Indivudually these queries run 100%

query1

```
SELECT year_entered, 
   month_entered,
   IFNULL(amount - @n, 0) amount_diff,
   @n := amount current_amount
  FROM
 (SELECT YEAR(date_entered) year_entered, 
     MONTHNAME(date_entered) month_entered, 
     SUM(amount) amount
FROM opportunities
INNER JOIN opportunities_cstm
ON ( opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c)
WHERE 
YEAR(opportunities.date_entered) >= YEAR(CURDATE())
AND  (`opportunities`.`deleted` <> '1') AND 
(opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Ultraspin'
OR 
opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Mycelx')
GROUP BY YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered)) q, 
(SELECT @n := NULL) n
```

query 2

```
SELECT year_entered, 
   month_entered,
   IFNULL(id - @n, 0) id_diff,
       @n := id current_id
  FROM
 (SELECT YEAR(date_entered) year_entered, 
         MONTHNAME(date_entered) month_entered, 
         COUNT(id) id
    FROM opportunities
    INNER JOIN opportunities_cstm
    ON ( opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c)
 WHERE 
 YEAR(opportunities.date_entered) >= YEAR(CURDATE())
 AND  (`opportunities`.`deleted` <> '1') AND 
 (opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Ultraspin'
 OR 
 opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Mycelx')
   GROUP BY YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered)) q, 
 (SELECT @n := NULL) n
 ON year_entered = year_entered
```

I need to how the amount differences and the count differences in one query, Want to user jasper reports to report this out, or if someone could help in php return rows?

just dont know how to get both queries in and returning them next to each other

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT year_entered, 
   month_entered,
   query1.amount_diff,
   query2.id_diff FROM
        (SELECT year_entered, 
           month_entered,
           IFNULL(amount - @n, 0) amount_diff,
           @n := amount current_amount
          FROM
         (SELECT YEAR(date_entered) year_entered, 
             MONTHNAME(date_entered) month_entered, 
             SUM(amount) amount
        FROM opportunities
        INNER JOIN opportunities_cstm
        ON ( opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c)
        WHERE 
        YEAR(opportunities.date_entered) >= YEAR(CURDATE())
        AND  (`opportunities`.`deleted` <> '1') AND 
        (opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Ultraspin'
        OR 
        opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Mycelx')
        GROUP BY YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered)) q, 
        (SELECT @n := NULL) n) query1 JOIN (
            SELECT year_entered, 
               month_entered,
               IFNULL(id - @n, 0) id_diff,
                   @n := id current_id
              FROM
             (SELECT YEAR(date_entered) year_entered, 
                     MONTHNAME(date_entered) month_entered, 
                     COUNT(id) id
                FROM opportunities
                INNER JOIN opportunities_cstm
                ON ( opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c)
             WHERE 
             YEAR(opportunities.date_entered) >= YEAR(CURDATE())
             AND  (`opportunities`.`deleted` <> '1') AND 
             (opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Ultraspin'
             OR 
             opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Mycelx')
               GROUP BY YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered)) q, 
             (SELECT @n := NULL) n
             ON year_entered = year_entered
        ) query2 ON query1.year_entered = query2.year_entered AND query1.month_entered = query2.month_entered
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT year_entered, 
       month_entered,
       IFNULL(amount - @n, 0) amount_diff,
       IFNULL(id - @a, 0) id_diff,
       @n := amount current_amount,
       @i := id current_id
FROM (SELECT YEAR(date_entered) year_entered, 
             MONTHNAME(date_entered) month_entered, 
             SUM(amount) amount,
             COUNT(id) id
      FROM opportunities
      INNER JOIN opportunities_cstm
      ON ( opportunities.id = opportunities_cstm.id_c)
      WHERE YEAR(opportunities.date_entered) >= YEAR(CURDATE())
            AND  (`opportunities`.`deleted` <> '1')
            AND (opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Ultraspin'
            OR opportunities_cstm.interest_level_c = 'Mycelx')
      GROUP BY YEAR(date_entered), MONTH(date_entered)) q,
     (SELECT @n := NULL, @i := NULL) n
```